# Значение корней в русских двухсоставных именах

Tags: имена-собственные

Прочла несколько работ о славянских и древнерусских двухсоставных именах. 
Оказалось, что значения корней каждый трактует как хочет! Например, один и тот же корень *-слав* награждают разными смыслами ("известный", "славный", "славящий", "славянский"). В Интернете сплошь и рядом встречаются тексты, в которых, например, один и тот же автор  "Ярослав" переводит как  "известный ярым характером" , а "Станислав" - "стань славным". Видя такие расхождения, доверять суждениям таких авторов сложно, кажется, это беспорядок и народная этимология. 
Мне интуиция подсказывает, что у каждого из наиболее распространённых корней всё-таки есть единственный смысл, не зависящий от второго корня в имени. Например, по логике словаря Фасмера, *-слав* не имел изначального значения "славный", думаю, и к именам это относится.

Прошу Вас написать значения наиболее распространённых корней древнерусских и славянских имён:

1. -слав
2. -мир
3. -гость
4. -нег.

Благодарю.

Answer (score 2):

Сразу оговорюсь, здесь не всё - корни.

> -слав

Это действительно корень, значения - известный, славный, в древнерусском большой разницы не было, слава - это и есть известность. Фасмер, насколько понимаю, об этом и говорит.

Ярослав "переведено" у Вас правильно, Станислав - несколько однобоко. Станистав - скорее известный своим "станом" - т.е. городом. Это навскидку, но точно не "стань" - нехарактерно для славянских имен. Точно также "Ростислав" - не "расти славным", скорее  "общеизвестный". Если не вообще "известный ростом". 
Вообще во всех подобных именах первая часть обычно отвечает за смысл, т.е "переводиться" должна существительным, вторая - глаголом или причастием. Иное вызывает сомнение в компетенции автора.

> -мир

Этого корня в славянских именах нет и никогда не было.
Ошибочная интерпретация древнерусского мѣръ - с тем же значением "славный", "знаменитый".
Владимир (Володимѣръ) - известный властью, имеющий власть.

> -гость

Не сталкивался. Примеры есть? 
"Гостомысл" - весьма древнее образование с темной этимологией первой части, возможно просто "мудрейший". Но сводить его к "гость" нельзя, было бы "гостемысл".

Вообще значение "гость" в древнерусском - купец, обычно иноземный. В этом же значении у Пушкина: "Вот на берег вышли гости. Царь Салтан зовет их в гости".  Старое здесь значение перекликается с новым.

> -нег

Вряд ли корень, более напоминает притяжательный суффикс.
Единственный пример, что вспомнил, - Радонег, но это очень древнее языческое имя, видимо исходный (мужской) вариант для Радоница, т.е. "тот кто радует".

Comment: Спасибо!

1). –нег
Имена с окончанием -нег (из исторических документов, источник http://www.vrn-histpage.ru/page.php?Page=18)

Милонег
Уненег
Перенег
Рознег
Добронег
Миронег
Воинег 
Стоенег 
Доманег 
Паченег 
Чернег


В Новрогодских грамотах очень часто встречается уменьшительно-ласкательное Нежко.

Comment: 2). –гость
Доброгость, помню, у Тупикова (Словарь древнерусских имён).
А у  Баженовой («Славян родные имена»)  немало  такого типа имён, но у неё не только русские, а славянские. Причём когда я эту книгу читала, мне казалось, что этот тип часто встречается (видимо, потому что смысл мне был неясен, мой взор на них задерживался), но сейчас навскидку открыла, оказалось не так уж и часто,  нашла Домогость (южн. слав.). 
Может быть, сюда также можно отнести:  у западных славян был бог  Радегаст (Родигост).

Comment: 3). –мер (-мир)
В литературе  часто встречала, что Владимир – это Владимр с корнем –мер (я доверяю этому), но точно ли это верно для всех подобных имён? Здесь у меня два вопроса:
А). Так как очень много имён именно с окончанием –мир, причём и у остальных славян тоже,  можно ли на всех славян распространять древнерусскую «меру»? Может быть, были распространены оба варианта: и с корнем –мер, и с –мир?

Comment: Б). Если учесть, что во времена Средневековья был принцип наследования части имени от отца к сыну или дочери (исторические примеры отец  Володимер, сын Всеволод; отец Рогволод, дочь Рогнеда), может  быть,  (гипотетический пример) корень –мир из первой части имени отца (Мирослав) переходил в окончание имени сына (Любомир, Славомир)?

Comment: Могу наверняка ответить только на 3А).  
Вторая часть -мир - это всегда мѣръ. Сам узнал об этом совершенно случайно, какое-то имя встретилось в берестяной грамоте, и во время ежегодного обсуждения кто-то (Зализняк, кажется) недвусмысленно указал на принципиальную невозможность другой трактовки этого мѣръ. В отношении ЗБ) - не помню, распространялось ли сказанное и на первую часть такого подобных имен, по похоже, что так, имена в общем-то складывались из ограниченного числа повторяющихся корней.  
По поводу всего остального - просто не компетентен.  
Но подумаю, хотя я и полнейший дилетант.

Comment: Или  имя  Борислав - славный  в  борьбе,  борец  за  славу,  славящий  борьбу ?

Comment: Скорее всего - как и все прочие "славы" - известный т.е. прославившийся своей борьбой.

Answer (score 0):

В таких  сложных  именах  кроме  значения  корней  интересно  ещё  и  значение  выводимое  из  их  сочетания.   Милонег  -  это  милый  и  нежный,  или  милый  к  неге,  или  ещё  как ?  Мне  кажется,  что  современная  расшифровка  всегда  несколько  притянута  за  уши.  Относительно  имени  Владимир  ещё  интересней.  "Красное солнышко"  оказался  главнее  всех  своих  братьев,  но  кто  это  мог  предвидеть,  когда  он  имя  получил.  От  имени  отца  он  не  получил  ни  одного  корня.  Да  ещё  есть  версия,  что  Владимир - это  славянизированоё  германское  имя Вольдемар.

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже давно задаюсь вопросом, по крайней мере в отношении значения корня -слав- в славянских именах. К сожалению, я не владею ни доступом к первоисточникам, ни знаниями и интерпритациями, чтобы произвести более-менее достоверные домыслы, но всё же голова у меня на плечах и она умеет думать, и думает, что корень -слав- всё-таки несёт в себе значение не "славный", "известный" потому что я не вижу логики в поименовании ребенка известным? Новородженного ребенка. А как я понял, имена с корнем -слав- были именами даваемые при рождении (а не церковное имя или прозвище, которые давались гораздо позднее). Зато известно, что предки наши называли себя словом "славяне", в котором так же имеется корень -слав-, а если провести аналогию с корнем -рус-, получим, славянин - русич, русс - ? Так что я думаю, что то пустое место как раз и заполняется словом, состоящим только из корня -слав-, исходя из этой логики, можно предположить, что, Ярослав - пылкий славянин, Станислав - стройный славянин (вспоминаем, что значит слово "стан") и так далее.
Говоря сразу, что могу быть не прав. Я лишь высказал свою точку зрения.